# How to write a file with the permissions of the owner in perl

Tags: perl, file, file-io, file-permissions

I am writing a script and I need to be able to write additional configuration information to a `.conf` file.

#### The Issue:

The issue is I am unable to write additional data to a file due to a permission issue. Here is the code I am using:

```
my $conf = "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf";
open my $handle, ">>", $conf or die $!;
# spacing counts, hence the indentation
print $handle 'fastcgi.server = (
    ".php" => ((
        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
        "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket"
    ))
)'."\n";
close $handle;
```

Since the `lighttpd.conf` file is under the umbrella of `root:root`, I'm unable to write it without doing something along the lines of:

```
system("sudo chown $USER:$USER /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf");
# write to file...
system("sudo chown root:root /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf");
```

The above seems rather hackish to me and I'd rather avoid this.

#### The Question

Are there more elegant ways to go about writing this information to the file? Perhaps a BASH command I am unaware of?

Comment: `sudo chown root:root /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` is also a shell command and can be executed in `bash` too!

Comment: Don't chown on a root file! Use `sudo perl_script.pl` which runs the Perl script under root. Do not put `sudo` in a shell script, ever!

Comment: When you say, "Do not put `sudo` in a shell script, ever!" you mean this? `system("sudo ...")`, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved

Per [shawncorey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604642/shawnhcorey) recommendation, I removed all instances where I had

```
 system("sudo [command]");
```

and ran the script as follows:

```
 sudo ./test.pl
```

Needless to say it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -2):

You can run 'chown' to changes the owner (and group) of a list of files in perl.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$cnt = chown $uid, $gid, 'foo', 'bar';
chown $uid, $gid, @filenames;
```